# Problem mapping fields with a Database Target

Tags: nlog

I am having a problem getting this to work correctly. I tried it with a straight INSERT statement and a Stored Proc also with the same bad results.
On the example below, the Version number is ending up in the ErrorMsg field in the database. The Log Level ends up in the UserName. Any idea  why is this happening? The commandtext statement is correct.

```
<target xsi:type="Database"
          name="dberrorlog"
          connectionStringName="Logger"
          keepConnection="true"
          useTransactions="true" >
      <commandText>
        INSERT INTO [Logs].[LogError]
        ([ProgName], [CreatedDate], [CompName], [LogLevel], [UserName], [ErrorMsg], [Version], [SourceMethod], [StackTrace])
        VALUES
        (@ProgName, @CreatedDate, @CompName, @LogLevel, @UserName, @ErrorMsg, @Version, @SourceMethod, @StackTrace)
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@ProgName" layout="MyProgram"/>
      <parameter name="@CreatedDate" layout="${date:format=MM\-dd\-yyyy HH\:mm\:ss}"/>
      <parameter name="@CompName" layout="${machinename}"/>
      <parameter name="@LogLevel" layout="${level}"/>
      <parameter name="@UserName" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}"/>
      <parameter name="@ErrorMsg" layout="${exception:format=ToString}"/>
      <parameter name="@Version"  layout="1.0.0.0"/>
      <parameter name="@SourceMethod" layout="${callsite}"/>
      <parameter name="@StackTrace"   layout="${stacktrace:format=Raw}"/>
</target>
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you run the command text as a query does it execute correctly? If so, the next thing I would do is create a log to a text file and explicitly output each of the values to make sure they are not blank and that they contain data that you expect and in the format that you expect. Lastly have a read of http://nlog-project.org/forum#nabble-td1685540 It might help.